# Using django form validation to check item inventory

Tags: python, django, validation, formset

Im using an inline formset for an ordering system. The user selects an item and then enter the amount of that item they want.

The formset uses this model form. I'm trying to use the clean method to see if there is inventory left for the selected item. The error I get is 'OrderedItemForm' object has no attribute 'item'

```
class OrderedItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
item = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Item.objects.all(), empty_label="(Nothing)")
quantity = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1)

def clean(self):
    count = Item.objects.get(pk=self.item.pk)
    if(self.quantity > count):
        raise ValidationError("Insufficient inventory")

class Meta:
    model = OrderedItem
```

Here is the models I use:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    inventory = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, default=0.0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    setup = models.DateTimeField()
    takedown = models.DateTimeField()
    address = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s's order" % self.customer

class OrderedItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='ordered_items')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='orders')
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s (%d)" % (self.item, self.quantity)
```

And the view:

```
def order_form(request):
    OrderedItemFormset = get_ordereditem_formset(OrderedItemForm, extra=1, can_delete=True)
    order = Order()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST, instance=order)
        formset = OrderedItemFormset(request.POST, instance=order)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            formset.save()

            total = 0.0
            data = []
            for item in order.ordered_items.all():
                data.append({
                    'order': item.order.id,
                    'product': str(item.item.name),
                    'quantity': item.quantity,
                    'total': (item.item.price*item.quantity)
                })
                total += float((item.item.price*item.quantity))


            return render(request, "order_success.html", {
                'ordered_items': data,
                'grand_total': total,
                'order_num': order.pk,
                'order_name': order.customer,
            })
    else:
        form = OrderForm(instance=order)
        formset = OrderedItemFormset(instance=order)
    return render(request, "order_form.html", {'form': form, 'formset': formset})
```

Answer (score 2):

The field data should be obtained from the form's `cleaned_data` dictionary:

```
def clean(self):
    item = self.cleaned_data['item']
    quantity = self.cleaned_data['quantity']
    if(quantity > item.inventory):
        raise ValidationError("Insufficient inventory")
```